# Squaring every digit in C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to square every digit of a number and return an integer with all the squared values. For example, if the inputted integer is `9119`, `811181` will come out, because 9 squared is 81 and 1 squared is 1. My attempt so far is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic; 

public class Kata
{
public static int SquareDigits(int n) {

    String inputNums = n + "";
    String[] digits = inputNums.Split("");
    String outputNums = "";


    foreach (string s in digits) {
      int i = Int32.Parse(s);
      var outputNum =  (i * i);
      outputNums += (outputNum);

    }

    return Int32.Parse(outputNums);

  }
}
```

However, I keep getting this error:

```
Test Failed
  Expected: 811181
  But was:  83156161
```

Can anyone please help me understand where I have gone wrong? I have tried to convert the integers back to strings in attempt to get them to concat but not add together, but I can't seem to arrive at the right value. I'm still relatively new to C# so any help is appreciated - thanks :)

Comment: Use the debugger and see what the output of `inputNums.Split("")` is. An alternate way would be to use `char[] digits = inputNums.ToArray()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `String[] digits = inputNums.Split("")` doesn't parse your string because of `Split("")`. You are sending empty string to Split function. You can use this function.

```
public static int SquareDigits(int n)
        {

            char[] digits = n.ToString();
            String result = "";
            foreach (char ch in digits)
            {
                double squared = Math.Pow(Int32.Parse(ch.ToString()),2);
                result += squared.ToString();
            }
            return Int32.Parse(result);
        }
```

Comment: `ToCharArray` is not necessary since `string` is a `IEnumerable<char>`.

Answer (score 6):

You can avoid formatting and parsing to a string by just doing math operations.

```
public static int SquareDigits(int n)
{
    int result = 0;
    int places = 0;

    // loop while n has digits.
    while(n > 0)
    {
        // Get the least significant digit
        int digit = n % 10;

        // Square the digit
        int square = digit * digit; 

        // Add the square to the result the number of places over
        result += (int)Math.Pow(10,places) * square;    

        // Increase the number of places by the size of the square (either 1 digit or 2)
        places += square > 10 ? 2 : 1;  

        // Removed the least significant digit
        n /= 10;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Note: you might want to go with `long` instead of `int` for the return type to allow for larger return types before you hit overflow.  Or even `BigInteger` to handle all possible positive `int` inputs.  Also obviously this returns 0 for any negative number.

Answer (score 2):

This does not work, since an empty string is not a valid separator for `String.Split`. But a string is an enumeration of characters. Enumerate the characters in a foreach-loop:

```
public static long SquareDigits(int n)
{
    string inputNums = n.ToString();
    string outputNums = "";

    foreach (char c in inputNums) {
        int i = c - '0';
        int outputNum = i * i;
        outputNums += outputNum;
    }
    return Int64.Parse(outputNums);
}
```

You can use the fact that a `char` is treated as a 16-bit integer type in C#. To get the corresponding numeric value of a digit, subtract the character `'0'` from the given character. E.g. `'5' - '0'` gives `5`. Note that `(int)'0'` is 48 (the character code of the character `'0'`) and `(int)'5'` is 53. 53 - 48 = 5.

I extended the range of possible inputs to `Int32.MaxValue` = 2147483647, by using a `long` or `System.Int64` as return type of the function.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
int num = 9119;
string squared = "";
foreach (var c in num.ToString())
{
    int part = int.Parse(c.ToString());
    int square = part * part;
    squared += square.ToString();
}

int answer = int.Parse(squared);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the simplest solution.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic; 

public class Kata
{
public static UInt64 SquareDigits(int n) {
    string outputNums = "";
    foreach (char s in n.ToString()) {
        UInt64 i = UInt64.Parse(s.ToString());
        double outputNum =  Math.Pow(i, 2);
        outputNums += Convert.ToString(outputNum);
    }
    return Convert.ToUInt64(outputNums);
}
}
```

knowing that a number multiplied by itself is always positive we can use UInt64 which is an Int64 but with only positive numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this robust approach:

```
using System;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var value = 9119;

            if (!TrySquare(value, out var result))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed!");
                return;
            }

            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }

        private static bool TrySquare(int value, out int result)
        {
            result = 0;

            var builder = new StringBuilder();

            var input = value.ToString();

            foreach (var c in input)
            {
                var i = int.Parse(c.ToString());

                builder.Append(i * i);
            }

            // this might fail if number is too large

            return int.TryParse(builder.ToString(), out result);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just using string (like most other answers), you should use a `StringBuilder`. Also it's unnecessary to use `int` for the digit, `byte` is more than enough. Futhermore, this is a function that is well suited to be an extension to `int`.

```
public static int SquareDigits(this int number)
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("");
    foreach (char c in number.ToString())
    {
        byte digit = byte.Parse(c.ToString());
        builder.Append(digit * digit);
    }
    return int.Parse(builder.ToString());
}
```

Can be called like this:

```
int squared = 9119.SquareDigits(); // 811181
```

Edit:
To avoid overflow if the input is too big, you could use a `TryX` pattern.

```
bool TrySquareDigits(int number, out int squared)
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("");
    foreach (char c in number.ToString())
    {
        byte digit = byte.Parse(c.ToString());
        builder.Append(digit * digit);
    }
    return int.TryParse(builder.ToString(), out squared);
}
```

This can be called like this:

```
if (TrySquareDigits(9119, out int result)) { ... } // result = 811181
```

Answer (score 0):

There some other concerts;

- Keep in mind you don't want negative int's because the first item in the string would be a minus
- Since you're doing square root and multiple chars can happen, you can cache the result
- Use Linq..

My attempt is this

```
private static Dictionary<char, int> preComputed = new Dictionary<char, int> ();

public static void Main()
{
    var result = SquareDigits(9119);
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}

private static string SquareDigits(uint input)
{
    return string.Join(string.Empty, input.ToString().Select(x => Square(x)));
}

private static int Square(char  x) {
    if (preComputed.ContainsKey(x))
    {
        return preComputed[x];
    }

    var numberX = Int32.Parse(x.ToString());
    var squared = numberX* numberX;
    preComputed[x] = squared;
    return squared;
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/NOHXhs